# How to use RGB Color map in Blender

Tags: color

I apologize if Color map is not the proper name for it, I'm not sure what they would be called.
If anyone here played the old homeworld game, it uses and RGB color map to define team colors. I am trying to figure out how to apply this color map in blender and then use the nodes to change the colors defined by the map. here is the texture. if anyone knows what this is called please tell me so I can properly refer to it.

[image: Color Map]
[image: Defuse Map]
The red channel of the texture defines one color and the Green Channel defines the other, overlaying atop the Defuse map to create the finished texture. If someone knows how to use a texture like this in blender and could tell me or knows what I should look up to find more I would appreciate it.
Sorry if this is worded badly I don't use forums much.

Comment: Personally I would call it a mask.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply I will try the example you post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To separate channels use *Separate Colors Node*, results for red and green will be like this:

[image]

You can use this grayscale mask as the *factor* input for *Mix Node* to set desired color and then overlay (Mix Node, overlay blend mode) it over your image texture. That you can repeat for all color channels you got.

[image]

And here the resulting image for Green -> #fec14e, Red -> #666380 (difuse bake):

[image]

Note that the unwanted boundary lines between the colors are caused by the poor image quality of the mask. An image with sharp color transitions and without artefacts caused by lossy compression would create better outcome.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, i will start to try with the example you have given maybe this can help a bit more? 
For this mask, the Red is replaced by. 666380 (color hex code) and the green is replaced by fec14e (Hex Code) .and here is the diffuse map it overlays i will add to the question

Comment: I'm noticing that with my nodes. there edges are very hard, its either full color or full alpha, there is no semi transparent, on the right is the example in red, you can see how the edge is soft, but on the model on the orange spot it's hard and jagged 
https://gyazo.com/c7ab3b471fe21f539c54584b44842ca8

Comment: Hey there, your method worked well for the transparency, but the color is to bright? I'm not sure how to fix it. 
it should be the darker blue in my picture before. here is what i get with your node set up 
https://gyazo.com/8930a8a5ea8a34749c51dc53fa5fcafb

Comment: So I think the correct blend mode is Color, although Multiply or Overlay has a similar effect.

Comment: Hello there, thank you again for such a detailed reply. I have this version here, this is me manually. creating the color map in photoshop by separating the channels and much more to finally get the color I need. this is how it should look in blender. 
https://gyazo.com/9173f040879d5f1c68d1afa9807fb6e4
You can see the colors are much darker. The black is in deed alpha and uncolored it should be removed entirely. you are on the right track.

Comment: I am an idiot, I forgot about Separate Colors Node which makes creation of those masks piece of cake, no need for any group with substract/difference etc... Anyway I also fixed the color filters so now it is more like your image from photoshop. See updated blender file. But note that it is also affected by scene lighting, so it won't look exactly same.

Comment: Amazing! I'm so close, you are right on point. there is one thing, I am trying to bake the texture, but it keeps coming out very dark. am I doing something wrong with my set up? 
https://gyazo.com/484d402570c67c931dc1d860492c1325 this is how it should look but this is how its baking
https://gyazo.com/715a012afcb2ef2fcf2377409ff0f387
I've tried many baking methods.

Comment: It won't let me edit my comment. I noticed you output your combined texture without baking? how did you do that?

Comment: I haven't got that ship model, so I just created a plane (default mapping). The difference is that unlike diffuse baking my plane is affected by lights.

Comment: Maybe post also your psd file, so I can analyse what blend modes did you use for your layers in photoshop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141884/discussion-between-aelita-schaeffer-and-vajtus).